# Como converter um object em inteiro em Pyton 3?

Tags: python-3.x

Importei uns dados na Wikipedia e importei para o Pyton. Porém os dados que eram para serem inteiros estão na forma de object como na imagem abaixo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests

url = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_finais_da_Copa_do_Mundo_FIFA"
resposta = requests.get(url)
table = pd.read_html(resposta.text)
resposta = requests.get(url)
df = table[0]
df.head()
```

Eu usei o comando `df["Público Pagante"] = df["Público Pagante"].str.replace("[7]","").astype(int)`. Basicamente queria tirar esse [7] e esse (.). Acho que fazendo isso a variável transformará em inteiro. Mas, não sei como faz.

Answer (score 2):

O problema na substituição acontece porque, por padrão, a chamada [`df.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) considera o primeiro argumento como sendo uma expressão regular, portanto, é necessário colocar um caracter *escape* antes dos colchetes (`'['` e `']'`).

A expressão alterada fica:

```
df["Público Pagante"].str.replace("\[7\]", "")
```

Outra opção é indicar para o `replace` que o primeiro argumento não é uma expressão regular, acrescentando `regex = False` no comando:

```
df["Público Pagante"].str.replace("[7]", "", regex=False)
```

---

Para retirar o separador de milhar (`'.'`) e converter para inteiro, acrescente outro `replace` na expressão e converta com o comando `astype`:

```
df["Público Pagante"].str.replace("[7]", "", regex=False).str.replace(".", "", regex=False).astype(int)
```

Segue o resultado final do comando:

```
In [27]: df["Público Pagante"].str.replace("[7]", "", regex=False).str.replace(".", "").astype(int)
Out[27]:
0      68346
1      55000
...
19     84490
20     78011
Name: Público Pagante, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Show de bola. Obrigado